# Passing DBNull.Value and Empty textbox value to database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, dbnull

I have some textboxes on my page which can be empty because they are optional and I have this DAL code

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", FirstName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", LastName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisplayName", DisplayName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BirthDate", BirthDate));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", Gender));
```

Any of those fields can be empty. The problem is when they are empty I receive `Procedure XXX requires @FirstName which was not supplied`

Then I changed my code to

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? DBNull.Value : (object)FirstName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) ? DBNull.Value : (object) LastName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisplayName", String.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayName) ? DBNull.Value : (object) DisplayName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BirthDate", BirthDate.HasValue ? (object)BirthDate.Value : DBNull.Value));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", String.IsNullOrEmpty(Gender) ? DBNull.Value : (object) Gender));
```

But this looks messy to me especially the casting to `object` because ternary statement requires both value to be the same type.

Why is empty string or null string not treated `NULL` in the database? If I have to convert this to `DBNull.Value` is there a cleaner way? Saving the value as empty string in the database could have helped but query for `NULL` in the database will get messy too

Please give your advice on common practices or something close to that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, there are 2 more handy overloads:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@name").Value = value;
```

or

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
```

---

Personally I use the following extension method:

```
public static object DbNullIfNull(this object obj)
{
    return obj != null ? obj : DBNull.Value;
}

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value.DbNullIfNull());
```

or

```
public static object DbNullIfNullOrEmpty(this string str)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : (object)DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the command object because I abstracted it away into a Base class so I can use it with several database [avoiding dependency on a particular database]. I like the Extension methods approach. Thanks.

Comment: I think something is wrong with `DbNullIfNull`. I couldn't understand the logic there, so I typed it into my .NET 4.0 project, and it is certainly wrong! My guess is you meant to code `return (obj != null) ? obj : DBNull.Value;` instead of `return obj ? = null ? obj : DBNull.Value;` Just an FYI.

Comment: I know this is old, but the second function there doesn't work. To use the ternary operator, `str` and `DBNull.Value` must have an implicit conversion between one another (should be the same type). You'd have to use an if/else in this case.

Comment: @Curmudgeon: Thanks, updated, check it out.

Comment: @abatischev: Thanks, I submitted an edit but it got rejected -_-' I forgot about the (object) trick though, so it wasn't as pretty anyways :)

Answer (score 5):

A little re-factoring might make code less messy. Try this

```
dbParams.Add(SetDBNullIfEmpty("@FirstName", FirstName));
dbParams.Add(SetDBNullIfEmpty("@LastName", LastName));
dbParams.Add(SetDBNullIfEmpty("@DisplayName", DisplayName));
dbParams.Add(SetDBNullIfEmpty("@BirthDate", BirthDate));
dbParams.Add(SetDBNullIfEmpty("@Gender", Gender));

private SqlParameter SetDBNullIfEmpty(string parmName, string parmValue)
{
    return new SqlParameter(parmName, String.IsNullOrEmpty(parmValue) ? DBNull.Value : (object)parmValue));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can default the parameters in the stored procedure, making them optional.

```
create procedure XXX
(
   @FirstName nvarchar(50) = null,
   @LastName nvarchar(50) = null,
   ...
)
```

Comment: this also works but won't make my DAL portable, so I have to handle the null values in my code. I don't know if ORACLE allow default values for parameters. (+1) anyway